# Get coordinates of beginning and end of a sentence

Tags: javascript, coordinates

I have a `<span></span>`, within which a sentence resides. Like:

```
<span>A sentence residing within a span</span>
```

Is it possible to get the coordinates of the starting and ending letters of that sentence i.e "A" and "n" respectively on a Javascript event like `onmouseover` attached with that span?

The span is resides within a `div`. So

case - I: for the sentence

```
This is a sentence inline
```

The top and left is evaluated with respect to the letter "T" of the word "This".

case - II: for the sentence

```
... ... ... ... ... ... This is
a sentence broke into two lines.
```

The top is evaluated with respect to the letter "T" of the word "This" and the left is evaluated with respect to "a".

Is there any way to get the coordinates of the two terminals of a sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`span.getBoundingClientRect()`? [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536433%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Is `getBoundingClientRect()` works with all browser(specifically safari of mac)?

Comment: This will give you a rectangle containing the whole span rather than the coordinates of the start and end of the span's contents, which is what I think the OP wants.

Comment: @Tim, no, look carefully at case two.

Comment: Oh yes, it looks you're right. But then the OP asks for coordinates the "two terminals of the sentence", which suggests a different thing. Ah well, whatever the OP meant, I think between us we've answered it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the coordinates of the top left of the first character and the bottom right of the last character of the sentence, you can use the [`getClientRects()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getClientRects) method of the element. It's [supported in recent versions of all major browsers](http://help.dottoro.com/ljxsdaqk.php).

```
var rects = span.getClientRects();
var startTopLeft = { x: rects[0].left, y: rects[0].top; };
var lastRect = rects[rects.length - 1];
var endBottomRight = { x: lastRect.right, y: lastRect.bottom; };
```

Note that these coordinates are relative to the viewport rather than the document. If you need to position other elements using these coordinates, you'll need to account for scrolling.